# List of lists in Scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have a grid (that is declared as a `List (of Lists)`) and each `3*3` block for example is indexed as `0`, the next `3*3` block is indexed as `1`, etc.

I need to write a method that returns the elements (`integers`) in a particular block given an index.

For example : b(0) should give 1 0 0 4 1 2 7 0 0

```
1 0 0 | 4 0 2 | 5 0 7 |
4 1 2 | 0 0 3 | 6 8 0 |
7 0 0 | 0 0 9 | 0 0 1 |
----------------------
1 0 0 | 4 0 2 | 5 0 7 |
9 0 2 | 0 4 3 | 1 8 0 |
7 1 0 | 0 8 9 | 8 0 0 |
----------------------
1 0 0 | 4 0 2 | 5 0 7 |
4 0 2 | 0 1 9 | 6 2 0 |
7 0 0 | 0 0 9 | 0 0 1 |
----------------------
```

Comment: can you please give a clear example.

Answer (score 2):

```
  implicit class MatrixOps[T](val l: List[List[T]]) extends AnyVal {
    def getBlock(index: Int, size: Int = 3): List[T] = {
      l map (_ drop index * size) take size flatMap (_ take size)
    }
  }

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = List(
      List(1, 2, 3),
      List(4, 5, 6)
    )
    println(x.getBlock(0))
    println(x.getBlock(1))
  }
```

Comment: `|x|x|o|`, `|x|x|o|`, `|o|o|o|` (3 rows, respecfully), here is x denotes chosen block (of size 2), o -- rest of the items.

Comment: @flavian see edit in question

Comment: thanks can you please explain it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try with following function,

```
def block(i:Int, grid:List[List[Int]]) = grid.
  grouped(3).
  toList(i / 3).
  map(_.grouped(3).toList(i % 3))
```

Here's that example with nice print method

```
def print(q:List[List[Int]]) = q.map(_.mkString("\t")).mkString("\n")

val grid = (1 to 81).toList.grouped(9).toList

scala> print(block(1))
res37: String = 
   4    5   6
   13   14  15
   22   23  24
```

(Sorry, Im too lazy to write a sudoku board as an example :) )

To get the list of integers, try `flattern`.

```
scala> block(1).flattern
res38: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 22, 23, 34)
```

Comment: send the complete compilation error with pointer.